# How to specify in VS SDK to load my AsyncPackage immediately after Visual Studio is open?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

It can be in background, but the trigger must be opening Visual Studio or installing the extension into a running instance.

I am new to VS SDK and working off this example - https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/SolutionLoadEvents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following attribute to the VSPackage class in addition to your UICONTEXT.SolutionOpening:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
```

It will load your extension after opening Visual Studio, but not immediately as all extensions are loaded in background.

Installing the extension into a running VS instance is not possible.

Comment: The example code I am using was using some unknown guid as the UI context string. Yours worked better.